# xrandr settings changed. Display now won't run

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, screen, xrandr

I was trying to use xrandr to have a script to adjust my monitor resolution. As a test I ran

```
xrandr -s 1360x768
```

This should be a valid setting. It  killed the xserver. I changed to tty6 tried running

```
xrandr -s 1600x900
```

And rebooting but the reboot freezes on the KDE splash screen (I am using Kubuntu 14.04)

I can change to a TTY terminal to run xrandr but if I try -s or (-q) settings I get "can't open display"

If I try with "xrandr -d :0" I can use -q but I am not sure which display I would need.

Trying

```
xrandr -d :0 --output LVDS1 --auto
```

Returns: Configure ctrc 0 failed

I am on my phone so I can't easily paste in the result of

```
xrandr -d :0 -q
```

But I notice there is no * by any option. Should there be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `xrandr` permanently made a new settings file in

```
~/.kde/share/apps/kscreen
```

The old one was still available so I backed up the folder and deleted the newest settings file and everything works again.